# Email to SMS Gateway Verizon iPhone response goes to phone only

Tags: iphone, email, sms

I'm trying to send **SMS**' via email (so for example send an email like `9175550123@vtext.com`). The recipient gets an SMS from `me@gmail.com` (not my phone number).

In my `settings -> Messages -> Send & Receive`, I have 2 Addresses: phone number `8471234566` and my email `me@gmail.com`. It also happens to be that `me@gmail.com` is my Apple ID.

When the recipient also has a Verizon iPhone, if he responds, that response goes only to my phone (not as a response to my email), and on his phone it's sent as an iMessage.

This does not happen when one user is me (Verizon iPhone) and the other user is AT&T iPhone.

Additionally: if I remove `me@gmail.com` from the Send & Receive settings on the iPhone (so it just has my phone under Send & Receive), when the recipient replies the SMS is not delivered to either my phone or my email...

Any thoughts? If I send an SMS to `9175550123@vtext.com` from `me.junk@gmail.com`, which is not the Apple ID of any phone (or is associated with any phone), responses from the recipient do indeed go to my email. Even if I add `me.junk@gmail.com` as an address in my iPhone `settings -> Messages -> Send & Receive`, I can't reproduce the problem: responses from the recipient still go to email as they should (and are sent as regular Text Messages not iMessages from `9175550123`'s iPhone).

Answer (score 0):

I saw the same issue while using Amazon SES to send emails to Verizon customers.  Amazon did a bunch of digging and found that it was just an error with the way Verizon's gateway is set up.  I don't think there was ever a resolution.

https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=59605